# Mocking class properties Java/Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class written by somebody which exposes it properties as public without getters/setters.

Now I want to mock this class using Android Mocking framework.
I dont want to modify the class_under_test (unless required). I know its a bad programming practice, but is there a way to mock the properties like

```
AndroidMock.expect(myMockClass.name).andReturn('Scott');
```

I get exception when I run the testcase :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:174)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:156)
at com.google.android.testing.mocking.AndroidMock.expect(AndroidMock.java:264)
at com.akshat.test.TestPerson.testGetName(TestPerson.java:41)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

Comment: "I have a class written by somebody which exposes it properties as public without getters/setters."

I think you mean fields, not properties.  A property is normally a combination of a field, a getter, and a setter.  Google "java field property" (without the quotes) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Create a mock object for the class and assign a value to the properties variable.

```
Mock mock = Mock.create(ClassName.class);
mock.property = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to mock this class at all?  If the only behavior is trivial (i.e. fields), then you can use the class's fields just as they are.

E.g., if setting this up as a stub, do this in your test setup:

```
DependedOnClass dependedOnObject = new DependedOnClass();
dependedOnObject.name = "Scott";
objectUnderTest.dependedOnObject = dependedOnObject;    // inject the depended on object
```

or if setting this up as a mock, then do this in your assertions:

```
assertEquals("Scott", dependedOnObject.name);
```