# Can I mock a class whose fields don't have getter property

Tags: android, junit, mockito, powermockito

How to mock a class who don't have getter properties?. I am new in JUnit and mockito can anyone help me with this?

```
public class RegisterDeviceApiBody 
{
    @SerializedName("Login")
    private String mLogin;
    @SerializedName("Password")
    private String mPassword;
    @SerializedName("Nickname")
    private String mNickName;

    //setter login
    public void setLogin(final String login) {
        mLogin = login;
    }

    //setter password
    public void setPassword(final String password) {
        mPassword = password;
    }

    //setter nickname
    public void setNickName(final String nickName) {
        mNickName = nickName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try mocking? show the test case where you are trying to mock this

Comment: Possible duplicate- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910331/mocking-class-properties-java-android

Comment: @pvpkiran i tried using when operator, but as there is no getter i cant do it.